# Azure VM from ISO

Tags: azure

I have a Linux and Windows OS (iso media) not listed in Azure Market Place. How can I create a VM in Azure with those iso media? The ISO Media is in a Storage account file share. I have no other tools to create the Virtual Machines and Import to Azure.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot create an Azure VM from an ISO file. you can only create VMs from VHDs, Managed Disks or Managed Disk Images/Snapshots.

If you want to use this ISO in Azure you would need to use something like HyperV on premises to create a VM and then export the VHD and upload to Azure. Make sure you follow [this guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/upload-generalized-managed) to create the VHD in a format Azure can understand.

Comment: Just wanted to add that you can run nested virtualization in Azure that would allow you to run Hyper-V on a VM in Azure in case running Hyper-v on prem is a show stopper.  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nested-virtualization